# Why am I getting an Invalid argument error when writing data to cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm attempting to write data to cloud firestore using cloud functions but no matter what I do I'm getting an error message saying it's a bad request and its an invalid argument. I've tried changing the `data.text` as my only thought is it's not the correct call. I've been following Net Ninja's tutorial but in his he only deals with one field.

**Cloud Function**

```
exports.addHack = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('Data').add({
        name: data.text,
        gender: data.text,
        age: data.text,
        email: data.text,
        address: data.text,
        number: data.text
    })
});
```

**Javascript**
It's wrapped in a function because before the user presses the submit I have it check something and then it executes this function however that appears to work fine.

```
function submitHack() {
    const formContainer = document.querySelector('#formContainer');
    const addHack = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addHack');
    addHack({
        name: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
        gender: document.getElementById("genderField").value,
        age: document.getElementById("ageField").value,
        email: document.getElementById("emailField").value,
        address: document.getElementById("addressField").value,
        number: document.getElementById("phoneField").value
    })
    .then(() => {
        formContainer.reset();
        alert('Submission Successful! Enjoy your visit!')
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert(error.message);
    }) 
}
```

**HTML**
This is the form with all of the inputs I'm trying to write to the database including the button

```
    <section>
      <h1>Registration</h1>
      <div id="formContainer">
        <div class="item">
          <label>Full Name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="nameField" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>Gender:</label><br>
          <select id="genderField">
            <option value="null" selected>Please Select...</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>Age:</label><br>
          <input type="number" id="ageField">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>Email Address:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="emailField" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>Home Address:</label><br>
          <textarea type="text" id="addressField" placeholder="Enter Home Address"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>Phone Number:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="phoneField" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
          <label>I accept the <a id="termsLink" href="https://imgur.com/5lXi3Lc" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
        </div>
        <button class="call" id="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
```

**Error Message**

```
{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

Comment: Can you please post screenshot of the error?

Comment: Added it to my original post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the Callable Cloud Function as follows

```
addHack({
        name: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
        gender: document.getElementById("genderField").value,
        ...
    })
```

you are passing an object with several properties.

So, in the Cloud Function, you need to use these properties, as follows:

```
exports.addHack = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   
        const name = data.name;
        const gender = data.gender;        

        // ...
});
```

In addition, since it is a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) which executes an asynchronous operation (the Firestore `add()` method), you need to return a Promise. The data returned by the promise is sent back to the client.

So the following should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.addHack = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   
        const name = data.name;
        const gender = data.gender;        

        // ...

        return admin.firestore().collection('Data').add({
           name,
           gender,
           // ...
       
        })
        .then(() => {
            return {result: "success"}
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //  See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
        });

});
```

---

Of course you can also do:

```
exports.addHack = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

        return admin.firestore().collection('Data').add({
           name: data.name,
           gender: data.gender,
           // ...
        })
        .then(() => {
            return {result: "success"}
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //  See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
        });

});
```

---

Finally note that it seems that you are not calling the `submitHack()` function from the button. I would suggest you start by testing the Cloud Function with some constants, e.g. by doing:

```
const addHack = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addHack');
addHack({
    name: "test name",
    gender: "testGender",
    age: ... ,
    // ...
})
```

and when you are sure it works, work on the "wiring" between the form and the Cloud Function call.

Comment: Thanks I managed to get it working. Turns out when I was serving it using ```firebase serve``` chrome was loading an outdated version so it was working as it should of.